# Adjust DBSCAN in python so that it reads in my dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I have been using this code to try and cluster my latitude and longitude points from my file. However I think that it is actually creating random points instead of actually using my own points to find clusters.

I am still unsure of how this algorithm is working. If anyone can shed some light on how I would read in the data properly instead of creating random points which is what I think make_blobs is doing it would be much appreciated

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


##############################################################################
# Generate sample data
input = np.genfromtxt(open("dataset_import_noaddress.csv","rb"),delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
coordinates = np.delete(input, [0,1], 1)

X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=750, centers=coordinates, cluster_std=0.4,
                            random_state=0)

X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

##############################################################################
# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(labels_true, labels))
print("V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Rand Index: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Mutual Information: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"
      % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))

##############################################################################
# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels)))
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = 'k'

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

I know this may be a trivial question, but I am really just hoping to find out if there is a way to simply use my dataset, instead of creating a random dataset. Coordinates contains a matrix of all my points

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is creating random points.

That is why the function is called `make_blobs`, because it **makes blobs**. It also lives in the module `sklearn.datasets.samples_generator`, which further emphasizes it **generates sample datasets**.

It also rescales your data, but your should be using haversine distance.

Have you considered loading your data into a tool such as ELKI instead?
You don't seem to be too keen on writing code. Downloading random example code from the internet that you do not understand and running is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I am really new to coding so algorithms like this I am finding very hard. I will have a look at the ELKI toolkit. I was hoping though with this code that in the section to create random data i could just replace the random points generated with my points from my file, is this definitely not possibly ?

Comment: There is 0 benefit of having random points prior. You cannot reuse much of that sample code! Everything reusable is the method `DBSCAN`.